# Is the sentence "wherever and whenever you want" correct?

Tags: usage

Is the sentence "wherever and whenever you want" correct?

I have just come across this sentence. I think if it is correct it can be very useful in compositions.

Comment: Whatever you want will have a temporal element, i.e, you'll want it at some time. Not everything has a spatial element. So if I say, "I want to have happy thoughts," *whenever you want* is fine in reply since you can think things at any time. *wherever you want* sounds odd to me since there's never any constraint on where you can think. If I say, "I want to sing," than an expansive permission would include time ("whenever") and place ("wherever").

Answer (score 0):

> *wherever and whenever you want*

This is not a sentence but a noun phrase, typically occurring in 'free choice' relative contructions. The crucial point is that the *ever* component marks the phrase as non-referential: there is no reference to any particular place or time. For example:

*You can go whenever and wherever you want*

can be glossed as "You can go any time and any place you want".